Is it possible to configure Tomcat to use certificates in the Local Machine from a Global Managed Service Account?
Similar to the question: Can I store certificates in the personal store of a virtual service account?
I'm trying to access a certificate in the local machine My (personal) store from a service running with Global Managed Service Account defined in Active Directory as "account1$"
If I grant special read access permissions to any local or domain user, it can access when running a program from CLI.
If I give Managed Service Account (account1$) read and full access to the certificate, the service returns an access denied error for the keystore.
Service is using Java (tomcat), but I know the issue is not in Java because I'm using jdk 11.0.23 and it works when launched from the console.
24-Jun-2024 17:01:11.432 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]
        org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:1051)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:556)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:1045)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:724)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:746)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:305)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:475)
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.security.KeyStoreException: Access is denied.
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:107)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:71)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:235)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1227)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1240)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:80)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:1048)
                ... 13 more
        Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.security.KeyStoreException: Access is denied.
                at jdk.crypto.mscapi/sun.security.mscapi.CKeyStore.engineLoad(CKeyStore.java:735)
                at jdk.crypto.mscapi/sun.security.mscapi.CKeyStore$MYLocalMachine.engineLoad(CKeyStore.java:72)
                at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1479)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.security.KeyStoreUtil.load(KeyStoreUtil.java:69)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getStore(SSLUtilBase.java:217)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLHostConfigCertificate.getCertificateKeystore(SSLHostConfigCertificate.java:207)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getKeyManagers(SSLUtilBase.java:283)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.createSSLContext(SSLUtilBase.java:247)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:105)
                ... 20 more
        Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: Access is denied.
                at jdk.crypto.mscapi/sun.security.mscapi.CKeyStore.loadKeysOrCertificateChains(Native Method)
                at jdk.crypto.mscapi/sun.security.mscapi.CKeyStore.engineLoad(CKeyStore.java:732)
                ... 28 more


My guess is that access denied is for the store, not the certificate. Probably the options specified or asserted when opening the store. What does the code look like that opens and enumerates the store?

Good point @GregAskew! I should check the tomcat and source, as using an standard example with jdk libraries works. I also just found that giving the Managed account local Admin rights seems to advance. Error doesn't appear, but it is not possible to connect to SSL port. I will continue with the investigation. Thanks!

Granting the Tomcat gMSA local admin rights would be a non-starter IMO.

I agree. This was only a test trying to find and limit the issue.

It seems that depending of the KeyStore used, it is not the same to use null or "". As seen on getStore() https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/9.0.65/java/org/apache/tomcat/util/net/SSLUtilBase.java I will do some tests changing  attributes in server.xml

Finally, I got a configuration that works with Certificate Storage. It is very specific, and I couldn't find any other until date.
It works, but in our environment there is a required manual step yet. I think it should be configured in Windows and is common for all programs requesting private key not special for Tomcat.
A dialog of Windows Security is shown asking to allow access, similar to UAC but for certificates.

The server.xml configuration used is
<Connector port="8443"
           scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true">
    <SSLHostConfig>
        <Certificate 
          certificateKeystoreType="Windows-MY-LOCALMACHINE"
             certificateKeystoreFile=""
             certificateKeyAlias="tomcat"/>
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>

I continue my research trying to use different ciphers and properties, because I won't be able to use the standard  without the . It is clear for me, that different internals libraries are used in Tomcat, so when I use the only the  it doesn't work and it won't find the key in the storage.
For the purpose of the initial question, I consider this solutions as valid, as Tomcat is able to work with the Windows Local Machine Certificate Storage.
Solution requirements:

JDK 11.0.20+ or JDK version with fixed bug https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8286790
Tested with Tomcat 9.0.63
Tested in Windows 2019

